# Can not find asset when Flame Game is used as a Dependency

Tags: flutter, flame

I'm developing a game using the Flutter Flame engine and have packaged the game to be used in another Flutter app. However, I'm encountering an issue where the game, when used as a package dependency in the host app, cannot find its image assets.

My Flame game has its assets located in assets/images/ and they are properly listed in the `pubspec.yaml` of the game package. It loads the image like this:

```
spriteImage = await Flame.images.load('abc.png');
```

I've included the game package as a dependency in my host app's `pubspec.yaml`. Despite the assets being accessible within the game package, when I run the host app, it stops with exception:

> Unable to load asset: "assets/images/abc.png"`

How can I ensure that my Flutter Flame game package can correctly load its assets when used as a dependency in another Flutter app?

Is there in Flame something like the `package` parameter in the Flutter:

```
Image.asset('assets/images/abc.png', package: 'my_game')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it out. The answer from [@Hamed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78182326/7798989) pointed me in the right direction.
I only had to adjust the prefix of the [flame image cache](https://pub.dev/documentation/flame/latest/cache/Images/prefix.html):

```dart
class MyGame extends FlameGame with ... {

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    images.prefix = 'packages/ma_package/assets/images/'; // <- added this line
   
...

  }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the implementation for `Image.asset`:

```dart
package == null ? assetName : 'packages/$package/$assetName';
```

Therefore, you can prefix your assets with `packages/your_package_name/`:

```dart
spriteImage = await Flame.images.load(
  await rootBundle.load(
    'packages/your_package_name/assets/images/abc.png',
  )
);
```