# How to show assets of plugin in parent project Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-asset

I have a parent project that is using another project like a plugin inside itself like this:

```
messaging:
  git:
  url: https://github.com/....
```

In the sub-project, some assets are working fine when I run the sub-project.
The assets are added in sub-projects normally like this:

```
- assets/icons
- lib
```

when I run the parent project and in it, I show a widget from the sub-project that has an asset icon I get this error:

```
The asset does not exist or has empty data.
```

Comment: Is the dependent project a plugin? (If so, it has an example app.) When you say they are working fine in the dependent project, do you mean in the example app of it? Remember that a plugin has two sets of everything (lib, assets, pubspec, etc) in the plugin bit and the example bit - which are you referring to above - needs a lot more detail. How, in the example app, are you referring to the assets (where it is working) - give examples. Carefully follow the instructions here: https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/assets/assets-and-images#from-packages

Comment: Well the comment below and the accepted answer were pretty useful
if anyone  had a problem, such as this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54740732/how-to-add-assets-in-flutter-package-plugin-development
can be helpful as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prefix your asset's path with package's name like this:

```
packages/messaging/assets/...
```

In some cases, you may need to use `rootBundle` to load assets.

This answer may help you:

[Can not find asset when Flame Game is used as a Dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78182326/9455518)